# Creating a time interval of x years in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time, intervals

I need to create a time interval in my dataset. The dataset is currently between the years 2005 and 2019. [2005, 2006, 2007, […] 2018, 2019]

However i need to group it into either a five or four year period -> [2005, 2010, 2015] or [2005, 2009, 2013, 2017].

The dataset have 533 obs. and 8 variables -> Country, year, code, xx, yy etc
so the change need to affect the other variables to so that the data is correct.

Am I making sene? can anyone help me with this?

I've tried using mutate

```
# Create a new column 'period' with 5-year intervals:
my_data <- my_data %>%
  mutate(period = 5 * (Year %/% 5))

# # Create a new column 'period' with 4-year intervals:
my_data <- my_data %>%
 mutate(period = 4 * (Year %/% 4))
```

however the four year period here includes the year 2004 (which doesn't exist in the original dataset) something that just makes me unsure to trust this -.-

I've also tried the seq function, but can't get it implemented correctly...

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data

```
df <- data.frame(Year = 2005:2019)
```

Get the 4 year interval

```
# the sequence
seq(min(df$Year), max(df$Year), 4)
[1] 2005 2009 2013 2017
```

as grouping variable using `cut`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(period = consecutive_id(cut(Year, 
    breaks = seq(min(Year), max(Year), 4), right=F)))
   Year period
1  2005      1
2  2006      1
3  2007      1
4  2008      1
5  2009      2
6  2010      2
7  2011      2
8  2012      2
9  2013      3
10 2014      3
11 2015      3
12 2016      3
13 2017      4
14 2018      4
15 2019      4
```

and equivalently the 5 year version

```
# the sequence
seq(min(df$Year), max(df$Year), 5)
[1] 2005 2010 2015
```

again as grouping variable using `cut`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(period = consecutive_id(cut(Year, 
    breaks = seq(min(Year), max(Year), 5), right=F)))
   Year period
1  2005      1
2  2006      1
3  2007      1
4  2008      1
5  2009      1
6  2010      2
7  2011      2
8  2012      2
9  2013      2
10 2014      2
11 2015      3
12 2016      3
13 2017      3
14 2018      3
15 2019      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when()` or `cut()` to do it:

```
df <- tibble(year = 2004:2017)

# A tibble: 14 × 1
    year
   <int>
 1  2004
 2  2005
 3  2006
 4  2007
 5  2008
 6  2009
 7  2010
 8  2011
 9  2012
10  2013
11  2014
12  2015
13  2016
14  2017
```

Using `case_when()`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(period = case_when(year %in% 2005:2008 ~ "2005-2008",
                            year %in% 2009:2012 ~ "2009-2012",
                            year %in% 2013:2017 ~ "2013-2017"))

# A tibble: 14 × 2
    year period   
   <int> <chr>    
 1  2004 NA       
 2  2005 2005-2008
 3  2006 2005-2008
 4  2007 2005-2008
 5  2008 2005-2008
 6  2009 2009-2012
 7  2010 2009-2012
 8  2011 2009-2012
 9  2012 2009-2012
10  2013 2013-2017
11  2014 2013-2017
12  2015 2013-2017
13  2016 2013-2017
14  2017 2013-2017
```

Using `cut()`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(period = cut(year, 
                      breaks = c(2004,2008,2012,2017), 
                      labels = c("2005-2008", "2009-2012", "2013-2017")))

# A tibble: 14 × 2
    year period   
   <int> <fct>    
 1  2004 NA       
 2  2005 2005-2008
 3  2006 2005-2008
 4  2007 2005-2008
 5  2008 2005-2008
 6  2009 2009-2012
 7  2010 2009-2012
 8  2011 2009-2012
 9  2012 2009-2012
10  2013 2013-2017
11  2014 2013-2017
12  2015 2013-2017
13  2016 2013-2017
14  2017 2013-2017
```